# Merging NDVI classified and unsupervised classified image?

Tags: arcgis-10.4, classification, ndvi

I have clipped forest area from an image and apply NDVI classification on forest area and in the remaining, I have done unsupervised classification.

So, I want to know after NDVI and unsupervised classification, how do I mosaic or merge them to get a single classified image for further processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge raster bands into single image (with 2 bands) using [Composite Bands](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/composite-bands.htm) tool. But is still unclear to me why do you need to do that. If you want to do mathemathical operations with raster's cell values - use [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm).

The other approach is:

1. [Convert](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) your raster classification results to vector format.
2. Use [overlay tools](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/an-overview-of-the-overlay-toolset.htm).